# Entity Framework 5 function imports

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF 5 Database First in one of my projects.

I've got a `stored procedure` where it returns data according to some conditions. the return type is the same if any of those conditions in the stored procedure is `true`.

but if `non of them` is `true`, the last statement in the stored procedure is `RETURN`. In Entity Framework, the return type of this stored procedure is mapped to a `complex type`.

If the above happens, I get the following error.
`The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Context.ComplexType'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.`

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of allowing the stored procedure to fall through to the `RETURN`, you could return an empty dataset when the condition is false:

`select * from dbo.Foos where 0 = 1`

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes, this will solve the problem. But isn't there a better way of doing it? I mean, it's not a problem with the Stored Procedure. It's something to do with EF.

Comment: I don't think so. I think that if you are trying to map your stored procedure to a complex type then you always need to return a dataset.